# what does this mean `const {latitude} = position.coords;`

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I was learning from a course and i encountered this code :

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
    const {latitude} = position.coords;
    const {longitude} = position.coords;
    console.log(lat,longitude);
    console.log(position);

  },
  function(){
    alert('could not get position');
  });
}
```

Can someone please explain me the meaning of this line of code ?
`const {latitude} = position.coords;` and `const {longitude} = position.coords;`
i would really appreciate an help.........

Please someone explain me the meaning of the line of code.

Comment: [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: [Object desctructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring)